# Are there performance drawbacks to using Widget Extensions in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, performance, dart

I started using extensions on the `Widget` class to build UIs to avoid nesting the code too much when very simple widget are required (like `Paddings`). So, with this approach, the following code:

```
Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
     child: Text('test'),
),
```

Would turn into this:

```
extension Pad on Widget {
  @pragma('vm:prefer-inline')
  Widget pad(double padding) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding), child: this);
}
```

and, when building the UI, I would use the extension like this:

```
const Text("test").pad(20.0),
```

However I was wondering if this approach would negatively impact performance. One possible way I think it might do it is that in the extension method, the `EdgeInsets.all` is not a const constructor, but beside that I can't find any other possible drawbacks.

Is there something I am missing or is this a valid approach to build UIs?